# Choice between front-end developer or business analyst role?

Tags: career-development, software-development, careers, career-switch, websites

I completed a degree in computer science mixed with business management and have 7 months experience as a front-end developer, I've enjoyed it but sometimes get quite overwhelmed. I think I doubt my own ability sometimes, I might just be being hard on myself. But I'm joining a new team in work and they said I could either join as a BA or a front-end developer.

The BA side of things appeals to me in that it is a bit more interpersonal and social. Does anybody have any advice for me when weighing up to persevere with front-end development or to try being a BA? What are career prospects like for both? What should I know about negative aspects to being a BA? I like front-end work am I just lacking in confidence?

Comment: Business analysts with developer experience, and vice versa, are extremely valuable in my experience. You can do very well for yourself if you know how to walk both lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried one, so if I were you I'd try the other just to get a better gauge of which skills I would prefer to focus on long term. At this point you're just feeling your way into a career path, so the more diverse experience the better.